# Essence of BiMap in Google collections

Tags: java, data-structures, guava

I am still quite puzzled at the [BiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) in [Google collections/Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). It was claimed that **The two bimaps are backed by the same data; any changes to one will appear in the other.**

I browsed through the source code, and I found the use of delegate in `ForwardingMap`. But in any actually subclass of `StandardBiMap`, I do see the data are put into both the forward and reverse map. So what is the essence, and why it claims to have saved space by keeping only one copy of the data? Is it just the actual objects are one set, but two distinct sets of references to these objects are still needed, one set maintained in forward map, and the other in reverse map? What is the essence of BiMap here, vs. the alternative approach where client just maintains too separate maps and do updates accordingly?

```
  private V putInBothMaps(K key, V value, boolean force) {
    boolean containedKey = containsKey(key);
    if (containedKey && Objects.equal(value, get(key))) {
      return value;
    }
    if (force) {
      inverse().remove(value);
    } else if (containsValue(value)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "value already present: " + value);
    }
    V oldValue = super.put(key, value);
    updateInverseMap(key, containedKey, oldValue, value);
    return oldValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Where do you see a claim that `BiMap` saves space by keeping only one copy of the data? `BiMap` just provides forward and inverse views of a set of entries that both stay consistent as that data is changed. The savings is in not having to manually manage two maps and ensure that both are updated in your own code (plus error checking for cases where duplicate values would be added to one of the maps, causing an inconsistent state)... just use a `BiMap` and let all that be handled for you.

It's not about saving space, it's about keeping your code simple, readable, and correct.

Comment: (Though to be sure, future implementations might indeed save space; I'm doing some experimenting on that myself right now.  And that's another advantage of using a library instead of rolling your own implementation: improvements come free.)

Comment: On that note, maybe I should add a discussion to the wiki about how `BiMap` is meant to replace this idiom, since I don't really give much detail there at the moment...

Comment: The claim that the two are "backed by the same data" is at least kind of misleading when there are two BiMaps and two backing Maps.  We probably ought to rephrase.
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html#inverse%28%29

Comment: I guess?  I mean, that's also an implementation-specific thing which may well change in the future.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, super old thread, I know, but is it still the case, that the BiMap has no specific memory optimization to store data in both map?

Comment: @jeremieS No, it is not.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, very interesting :) do you have any doc or anything explaining how you guys did it?

Comment: @jeremieS no, we don't.  It's an internal implementation detail.